# Angular js input box how to pass ng-model without change it?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox

i am trying to push an ng-model value inside an ng-controller array, using the input box.

It seems that when i check the box the ng-model propriety change:

**HERE THE PROBLEM**

[image]

### [image]

[image]

I just want that ng-model propriety won't change when the input is checked,
here my code

**json model**

```
[
 {
    "nomeservizio" : "Frameworks",
    "framewrok":[
        {
            "name":"nessuno",
            "costo": 40
        },
        {
            "name":"bootstrap",
            "costo": 0
        }
    ]
}]
```

**HTML**

```
    <div class="row" ng-repeat="voce in voices.data">
    <h4 style="color:#000;">{{voce.nomeservizio}}</h4>
    <div ng-repeat="cssframework in voce.framewrok">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="cssframework.costo"  ng-change="AggiornaTotale({{cssframework.costo}})"/>  
        <span>{{cssframework.name}}........<b>{{cssframework.costo | currency}}</b></span>
    </div>  
</div>

<div class="row">
    <h3>TOTALE: {{selectedVoices}}</h3>
</div>
```

**JS INSIDE CONTROLLER**

```
    $scope.AggiornaTotale = function(param) {
    $scope.selectedVoices = [];
    $scope.selectedVoices.push(param);
}
```

Comment: you are confusing value with checked state

Comment: can you be a little more specific please?

Comment: Why do you want this illogical behavior? I think you are on the wrong way to make work what you try to. Please explain it with such more details.

Comment: `ng-model` on a checkbox is not the same as the value for that checkbox. It is used to track the `checked` state. Your `costo` properties contain values

Comment: @lin i'm trying to pass the cssframework.costo value inside the controller, but without that mess in the images above

Comment: The question is, what you try to achieve, not what is going wrong in the way you try it.

Comment: @lin my goal is to store multiple value from checkboxes and inputs inside an array, so when i'm clicking in an checkbox, i want that the value inside ng-model or value is stored to the $scope.selectedVoices array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this solution provides:

- multiple value from checkboxes and inputs inside an array
- Values are stored to the $scope.selectedVoices as array when clicking the input

#### Why ever you want that kind of logic. This solution provides all stuff you talked about.

```js
    myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
    myApp.controller('testController', function ($scope) {

        $scope.selectedVoices = [];
        $scope.framework = [{
                    "name":"nessuno",
                    "costo": 40
                }, {
                    "name":"bootstrap",
                    "costo": 0
                }, {
                    "name":"bootstrap",
                    "costo": 20
                }
            ];

        $scope.click = function (key) {
            $scope.selectedVoices.push($scope.framework[key].costo);
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="testController">
    <div ng-repeat="(key, item) in framework">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-click="click(key)" />
        <span>{{item.name}} {{item.costo | currency}}</b></span>
    </div>
    <h1> {{ selectedVoices }}</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Cool! thankyou, i was confused by documentation in angular who want that true and false propriety, i understand that i not need to pass the same object of framework propriety

Answer (score 1):

Model Name for value and checkbox model should not be the same.

when you change checkbox  - the model inside cssframework object also is updated.

Please try something like that (look at model in checkbox input):

```
<div ng-repeat="cssframework in voce.framewrok">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="costo"  ng-change="AggiornaTotale({{cssframework.costo}})"/>  
        <span>{{cssframework.name}}........<b>{{cssframework.costo | currency}}</b></span>
</div>
```

At the end i think that ng-model in checkbox is unnecessary. You don`t use it in that example.

Comment: thankyou, i was a bit confused by ng-model and checkboxes true false propriety

Answer (score 1):

Basically what checkbox box does is that on check it makes ng-model value true and on uncheck `ng-model` value  false. You can use `ng-true-value` to set value says 40 for check box when it is checked. Along with this used `ng-model` value as shown below:

```
 <div class="row" ng-repeat="voce in voices.data">
    <div ng-repeat="cssframework in voce.framewrok">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="cssframework.costo[$index]" ng-true-value="voce"/>  
    </div>  
</div>
```

So that when to get the value of "cssframework.costo" in controller like this **console.log($scope.cssframework.costo)** you will get a array.